# Responsive Navbar Breaks Under 768px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, collapsable

Ok, so I'm trying to build a portfolio website for myself (partially for real-world use, partially as a req. for the FCC curriculum), and so far, I've almost have everything the way I want.

I have a navbar at the top of the page, and it looks and works the way I want it to at anything > 767px, but at that size or smaller it completely disappears. The actual bar itself stays visible, but the menu drop-down toggle doesn't appear, and the logo (placeholder) I'm using disappears as well, which I also don't want to happen.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong in my code that is causing this to happen? I've looked all over S.O. & Google, and haven't been able to find an answer that seems to solve my problem. Here's my code:

## HTML

```
<!-- "DOCTYPE" Declaration -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<!-- Start HTML -->
<html lang="en">

    <!-- Start HTML Header -->
    <head>
        <title>My Portfolio</title>

        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- Bootstrap.css -->
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- Font-Awesome -->
        <link href="elastic/css/elastic_grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- Elastic CSS -->
        <link href="mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!-- Custom CSS -->

        <!--Javascripts -->
        <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script><!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap jQuery -->
        <script src="jquery/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script><!-- "scrollTo" Smooth Scrolling jQuery plugin -->
        <!-- Elastic -->
        <script src="elastic/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script><!-- Modernizr -->
        <script src="elastic/js/classie.js"></script><!-- Classie -->
        <script src="elastic/js/elastic_grid.min.js"></script> <!-- Elastic -->
        <!-- Initializing & Customizing JS -->
        <script src="js/my.js"></script><!-- Personal Javascript for initializing & using Javascript & jQuery plugins -->

    </head>

    <!-- Start Page Body -->
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topNav" data-offset="75">

        <!-- Start Navigation -->
        <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

            <div class="navbar-header"> 

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="myNavbar" role="navigation">

                <!-- Site Logo -->
                <a href="#home"><img src="imgs/logo_ph.png" alt="Logo placeholder" class="navbar-brand img-responsive" /></a>

                <!-- Start Navbar Links -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pills">
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#about">About Me</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#footer"><i class="text-center fa fa-angle-double-down fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- End Navigation -->

        <!-- Start Site Container -->
        <div class="container container-fluid" id="home">

            <br><br>

            <!-- Start "About Me" Section -->
            <section id="about" class="secB center-block">
                <h1 class="text-center">About Me</h1>
                <br><br>
                <img class="me-left" src="imgs/me-1.png" alt="Me" />
                <p>This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
<img class="me-right" src="imgs/me-1.png" alt="Me" />
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text </p>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </section>
            <!-- End "About Me" Section -->

            <!-- Start "Portfolio" Section -->
            <section id="portfolio" class="secA center-block">
                <h1 class="text-center">Sample Work</h1>
                <br><br>
                <div id="portfolio">

                    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $("#portfolio").elastic_grid({
            'filterEffect': 'fallperspective',
            'hoverDirection': true,
            'hoverDelay': 0,
            'hoverInverse': false,
            'expandingSpeed': 500,
            'expandingHeight': 500,
                'items' :
                [
                    {
                        'title'         : 'Covers',
                        'description'   : ' A collection of media covers I\'ve designed',
                        'thumbnail'     : ['imgs/covers/s/1.jpg', 'imgs/covers/s/2.jpg'],
                        'large'         : ['imgs/covers/l/1.jpg', 'imgs/covers/l/2.jpg'],
                        'button_list'   :
                        [
                            { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                            { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                        ],
                        'tags'          : ['Covers']
                    },
                     {
                        'title'         : 'Logos',
                        'description'   : ' A collection of business logos I\'ve designed',
                        'thumbnail'     : ['imgs/logos/s/1.jpg', 'imgs/logos/s/2.jpg'],
                        'large'         : ['imgs/logos/l/1.jpg', 'imgs/logos/l/2.jpg'],
                        'button_list'   :
                        [
                            { 'title':'Demo', 'url' : 'http://bonchen.net/' },
                            { 'title':'Download', 'url':'http://porfolio.bonchen.net/'}
                        ],
                        'tags'          : ['Logos']
                    }
                ]
        });
    });
</script


                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- End "Portfolio" Section -->

            <!-- Start "Contact" Section -->
            <section id="contact" class="secB center-block">
            <h1 class="text-center">Hire Me!</h1>
            <h5 class="text-center">...or you know...just HMU to chat. :P</h5>
                <br><br>
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text This is some text 
                </section>
            <!-- End "Contact" Section -->


        <!-- End Site Container -->
        </div>

            <!-- Start "Footer" Section -->
                <footer class="footer center-block" id="footer">

                    <!-- Footer Content-->
                    <div class="footer-content">

                        <!-- Footer text -->
                        <div class="footer-text text-center">
                            <span class="text-primary">Port-FAUX-lio</span> | &copy; Husayn Muhammad 2016
                        </div>

                        <!-- Social Media -->
                        <div class="footer-icons-box text-center">
                            <div class="fa-stack fa-2x sm-icon">
                                <a href="mailto:cloud4xL@gmail.com">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fa-stack fa-2x sm-icon">
                                <a href="http://twitter.com/cloud4xL" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fa-stack fa-2x sm-icon">
                                <a href="http://freecodecamp.com/cloud4xL" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fa-stack fa-2x sm-icon">
                                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/husayn-muhammad-040614106?trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile" target="_blank">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>    

                    </div>
                </footer>
                <!-- End "Footer" Section -->

    <!-- End Body -->
    </body>

    <!-- End HTML -->
</html>
```

## CSS

```
body {

    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    min-width: 430px !important;

}

/****** TOP NAVIGATION STYLES ******/

.navbar {

    background-color: #f2f2f2 !important; /*#190c03*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}

.navbar-brand {

    float: left !important;
    height: auto !important;
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;

}

.navbar-brand:hover {

    transform: translateX(25px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;

}

.navbar-right {

    margin-right: 15px !important;

}

.navbar-header {

    position: relative !important;
    float: left !important;
    width: 100% !important;

}

.navbar-toggle {

    /* margin-top: 0px !important; */

}

.navbar ul {

    float: right !important;

}

.nav-pills > li {

    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background-color: #d8661A;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transition: box-shadow 0.4s, transform 0.4s;

}

.nav-pills > li:hover {

    transform: translateY(-5px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s;

}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a {

    background-color: transparent !important;

}

.nav-pills > li.active {

    transform: translateY(-5px);
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: white !important;
    background-color: #337ab7 !important;
    transition: transform 0.4s, color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;

}

.nav-pills > li a {

    color: white !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent !important;
    transition: color 0.4s, border-bottom 0.4s !important;

}


.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {

    color: white !important;

}

/****** HEADER IMAGE STYLES ******/

.mast {

    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 2%; 
    /* box-shadow: 0 4px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); */

}

/****** <SECTION> STYLES ******/

.secA, .secB {

    width: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4% 10% 8%;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.secA {

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    overflow: auto !important;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

.secB {

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

}

/****** ABOUT ME SECTION STYLES ******/

.me-left {

    float: left; 
    max-height: 200px; 
    border: 5px solid black; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    padding-left: 8px; 
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
    background-color: white; 
    transform: scaleX(-1);

}

.me-right {


    float: right; 
    max-height: 200px; 
    border: 5px solid black; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
    padding-left: 8px; 
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
    background-color: white

}

/*********************************

**********sdFilterMe CSS**********

#sdfm-wrapper img, 
.sdfm-overlay {

    //Define the WIDTH of sdFilterMe Images 
    width: 200px !important;
    //Define the HEIGHT of sdFilterMe Images
    height: 200px !important;
    border-radius: 7px;
    overflow: hidden !important;

}

.sdfm-inner-wrapper {

    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 5px !important;

}

.sdfm-overlay {

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 0.35em !important;
    text-overflow: clip !important;

}

.sdfm-overlay span {

    padding: 5% !important;
    margin: 8% auto !important;
    max-width: 85% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;

}

*********************************/

/****** FOOTER STYLES ******/

.footer {

    width: auto;
    /* min-height: 150px; */
    /*margin-bottom: 5px !important;*/
    background-color: #1b1d1e;
    padding: 1.5% 5%;
    z-index: 3;
    border-top: 1px solid red;

}

.footer-content {

    /* border: 1px solid yellow; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;

}

.footer-text {

    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
    width: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 0.73%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;

}

.footer-icons-box {

    /* border: 1px solid red; */
    width: auto;
    padding: auto;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-self: flex-end;

}

.sm-icon {

    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;

}

.fa-circle {

    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    transition: all 0.4s;

}

.footer-icons-box .fa-envelope, 
.fa-twitter, .fa-free-code-camp, .fa-linkedin {

    color: #1b1d1e;
    transform: scale(1, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s;

}

.footer-icons-box .fa-envelope:hover,
.fa-twitter:hover, .fa-free-code-camp:hover,
.fa-linkedin:hover  {

    color: #337ab7 !important;
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s;

}
```

Comment: `href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"` and `elastic_grid.min.css` thats controlling your responsive..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap navbar has a built in media queries that toggle certain class when you hit screen size specific to it. 
Here is a sample of media query that changes the properties of the class when screen > 768px.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
      }
  }

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 340px;
```

}

I noticed the scope of myNavbar that is being toggled includes the hamburger menu that you toggle it into.

```
<div class="navbar-header"> 

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse " id="myNavbar" role="navigation">

            <!-- Site Logo -->
            <a href="#home"><img src="imgs/logo_ph.png" alt="Logo placeholder" class="navbar-brand img-responsive" /></a>

            <!-- Start Navbar Links -->


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-pills">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#about">About Me</a>           </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#footer"><i class="text-center fa fa-angle-double-down fa-lg"></i></a></li>
            </ul>

            </div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"      data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
        </div>
```

Comment: This code block is from bootstrap and your code is expecting to collapse into hamburger menu.

Comment: Check out http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar the collapse  spans with icon-bar class will appear when screen is < 768px.

Comment: I noticed your target is included inside your toggle.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat's what it was! lol Something kept looking off about it to my eye when I looked at it...that's what it was.lol Fixed the problem right up jmag. :) Thanx for that. ;)

Now I just have to figure out how make the logo stay visible, make it responsive, keep the button vertically centered, and change the pills to bars in < 768px mode. lol Back to work.

Comment: I haven't learned to dynamically resize an image, but usually, I have different sizes of images and use media query to display them according to screen size.  Here is a good sample site. http://alistapart.com/ I hope it helps.